# NoClassDefFoundError using Scala class from Java

Tags: java, scala, interop, noclassdeffounderror

I have no experience with Scala, so this question may be elementary. I am trying to use Scala class from within Java, based on the "Person" example in this tutorial: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala

I create two source files, one Scala and one Java, as follows.

Person.scala:

```
class Person {
  def getName() = "Daniel Spiewak"
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.getName();
  }
}
```

I can compile (with a warning I don't understand), but I get a ClassNotFoundException when I try to run the program.

```
$ scalac Person.scala
$ javac Test.java
./Person.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature': class file for scala.reflect.ScalaSignature not found
1 warning
$ java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at Test.main(Test.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 13 more
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Cause for the exception is [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)  please review

Comment: Did you include scala-library.jar in your classpath?

Comment: While trying the same example I got below error, please help..

`C:\Users\user1\Desktop>java -cp .:scala-library-2.11.8.jar Test

Error: Could not find or load main class Test`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to include the Scala runtime library to be able to use Scala classes. This is the cause of both the compiler warning and the error at runtime.

Try this

```
 java -cp .:scala-library.jar Test
```

(the name of the jar file might be different, but the point is to add it to your classpath).

Comment: Knew it would be something mundane. Thanks!

Comment: how can I add this library to my CLASSPATH when using Maven?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Do you use Maven to build or to run your application?

Comment: @Thio I use Maven for both

Comment: @Thilo , Im getting below error,

`C:\Users\user\Desktop>java -cp .:scala-library-2.11.8.jar Test`
`Error: Could not find or load main class Test`

Please advise

Comment: Where is your `Test.class`? Is the class in a package?

Answer (score 2):

Did you put scala-library.jar in your classpath? Seems you forgot this, so JVM cannot find some internal class for Scala runtime.

In your link http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala:

> Just stick scala-library.jar on your classpath and all of your Scala
>   classes should be readily available within your Java application.